# Can i rename filename before upload in angular js directive?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I used the following code to upload file. Its working fine but I want to rename the selected file before upload to avoid redundancy of files. Is it possible i worked many ways but i can't

```
     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);

     myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })

           .success(function(){
           })

           .error(function(){
           });
        }
     }]);

     myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
     }]);
```

Comment: Make server script rename files.

Comment: what @dfsq said since backend will know if files should be renamed (check for existence) and beside `element[0].files[0]` will output a file object including name, where you can change it

Comment: Ok i found out the solution as @dfsq,@maurycy said